# LTSpice capacitance dependend on voltage source

Tags: voltage, simulation, ltspice, capacitance

I am looking for a way to change the value of a capacitance dependent on the voltage source of the circuit.

How do I create a voltage dependent capacitor in LT spice?

Edit:
Two capacitances in a row are connected to a voltage source. The voltage source has a defined slope of the voltage. One capacitance shall be dependend (nonlinear) on the current voltage that the voltage source outputs. Example:::: Voltage (Power supply)= 200V -> Capacitor_1 = 10uF :::: Voltage (Power supply)= 400V -> Capacitor_1 = 1uF

Comment: What methods have you found so far and, importantly, what is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for a voltage dependent capacitor? Not clear what is the voltage source of the circuit and I am sure that it is not a general name.

Comment: I know that I can change the Cap with .step param, but then ltspice outputs various simulations of the steps.

What I have is this:
Two capacitances in a row are connected to a voltage source. The voltage source has a defined slope of the voltage. One capacitance shall be dependend (nonlinear) on the current voltage that the voltage source outputs.
Example::::
Voltage (Power supply)= 200V -> Capacitor_1 = 10uF ::::
Voltage (Power supply)= 400V -> Capacitor_1 = 1uF

Comment: Soderdaen, please edit your question and add the details from your comment.

Comment: State your purposes. Is this for the purposes of improving a MOSFET model? Do you want a two-terminal device that varies its capacitance based upon the impressed voltage? Do you want a 4-terminal device that is separately controlled? Do you want this table-based? ***One sentence does not a question make!*** And yes, I can see your comment. Put this and other information into good form in the question.

Comment: Edited the question...

Answer (score 3):

The behavioural elements include, besides the voltage and current, resistor, inductor, and capacitor. If you ran a quick search through the manual you would have found out quicker than it would have taken you to ask here: *LTspice > Circuit Elements > C*, bottom. Simply place a capacitor and add `Q=<...>` as the value. If the formula includes `x`, that signifies a derivative of the current, so your expression needs to be integrated first -- unless you don't need `x`, it can be done, for example external voltage, in your case.

So, for example, if you want your capacitance to vary according to \$\sin x\$, then you have to integrate that first, which gives you \$-cos x\$:

[image: behcap]

See the expression is `-cos(x)`, whre `x` is the derivative of the current. The driving voltage is a unity ramp, which means the current through the capacitor is directly its value (`I(C1)`). The behavioural voltage is for confirmation, `V(test)`, which shows the same sine. Here, for reasons of clarity, I avoided dividing by 2\$\pi\$, so that the current has a different amplitude; had I not, the current and the voltage would have overlapped and it would not have been clear.

---

Being a behavioural element, it is dependent on *time* and its effects, in LTspice, in addition to the derivative of the current you risk getting a lot of noise, so be careful what you wish for.