# Variable-Gap Capacitors in LTSpice

Tags: capacitor, inductor, variable, non-linear, behavioral-source

I have seen several blog posts that discuss the concept of a nonlinear capacitor (or inductor) [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499278/how-to-model-an-inductor-using-a-behavioural-voltage-source-in-ltspice-to-get-t), [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393905/simulating-a-variable-mutual-inductance-model), and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380581/ltspice-capacitance-dependend-on-voltage-source). Thanks to a concerned citizen for the references.

I'm still struggling with the execution of this for my capacitor. Below is a screenshot of the capacitor I care about in a schematic. I ultimately want this variable-gap capacitor to have a time-dependent capacitance, given by C = eps*A/(g0+g(t)). You can ignore the "disp sin(wt)," that was simply messing around.

[image]

I have made simple circuits with a behavioral voltage source and I have changed the capacitance to be expressed in terms of charge, i.e., Q = x*C (where C was just some constant, for testing, as shown below). In that equation, x is the voltage drop across the capacitor, per the LTSpice manual. I looked at the current through it and that is simply the derivative of the charge, so I end up with a cosine wave due to the sine wave voltage input. This makes sense.

[image]

My notion as of now is to try and get the current in this second image to be equal to the variable-gap capacitance (by using some behavioral voltage source that is a function of g(t)). But even if this were to work (which it may not, please let me know otherwise), I'm not sure how to link this to the capacitor in my original schematic. I can't figure out how to set the capacitance value equal to a current (i.e., how do I link the capacitance in the first figure to the capacitance in the second figure?). I have tried net labels.

I hope my explanation was clear and I appreciate any time/effort provided in explaining things.

Sincerly, a mechanical engineer with little Spice experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the manual, `x` is a special variable and for C it's the voltage across the device (so \$i=C\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\$, thus \$v\$ is derived), and for L it's the current through it (so \$v=L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}\$, thus \$i\$ is derived). But `x` is not a mandatory variable, that is, just because it's there it doesn't mean you have to use it; it just provides a commodity for notations, in case you use it.

That said, the manual also says:

> LTspice will compile this expression and symbolically differentiate it with respect to all the variables, finding the partial derivative's that correspond to capacitances.

Thus having an expression as `Q=x*V(ref)` means both `x` and `V(ref)` will be differentiated. For your case, you have a rational expression w.r.t. the variable, `g(t)`. Then, mathematically, your expression will need to be integrated so that its derivative will give you the variation for the resulting capacitance:

$$\int_x\frac{A\epsilon}{d\pm x}=\pm A\epsilon\log(d\pm x)$$

Let \$x\$ be represented by `V(g)`, which is the voltage that gives the "raw" displacement of the plates. Then, the expression that needs to be used with a behavioiural capacitor is:

`Q = A * epsilon * log( d + V(g) )`

for `d + x`, and

`Q = -A * epsilon * log( d - V(g) )`

for negative `d - x`. You could also use:

`Q = sgn(V(g)) * A * epsilon * log( d + sgn(V(g)) * V(g) )`

but you should be careful because `sgn()` is a discontinuous function, and differentiating that will most probably cause more problems than not. Note that there is no `x`, and the only time-variable is `V(g)`.

But if this is used in LTspice, it doesn't work as expected:

[image: test]

`V1`, by generating a unity 1 V/s ramp, will make its derivative 1, leaving the value of the capacitor to be read in Amperes. `C1` is supposed to have what I explained above, but the current through it doesn't show the expected graph. That's because `V(g)` is a sine in itself, which means the formula becomes (\$m\$ being the magnitude of `V(g)`):

$$\int_t\frac{A\epsilon}{d+m\sin(\omega t)}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{2A\epsilon}{\omega\sqrt{d^2-m^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2d\sin(\omega t)}{\cos(\omega t)+1}+2m}{2\sqrt{d^2-m^2}}\right)$$

If you plug in the values, you end up with the expression of `C5`, which is shown separate of the rest and truncated, since there is a *lot* of noise in there.

Fortunately, there are alternatives in making a time-variable capacitor, shown in the three boxed versions to the right. All three are plotted against `I(Rtest)` which is supposed to give the correct variation and, sure enough, they all are the same, but `C3` and `C4` have numerical issues, while `I(B2)`, the tried-and-tested version sine SPICE itself, is the most reliable here.

The group `E1`, `C2`, and `B2` form an equivalent variable capacitor. `C2` is supposed to have the fixed capacitor's value, but here I omitted `d` to allow the expression for `B2` to be written in a more readable format. The usage is in the very similar manner described in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/499278/95619).

Here's the source for the `.asc` file, copy-paste and save as `some_name.asc` (be careful to not end up as `some_name.asc.txt`!):

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1776 880
WIRE 480 80 384 80
WIRE 160 96 112 96
WIRE 736 240 656 240
WIRE 816 240 736 240
WIRE 960 240 864 240
WIRE 208 256 112 256
WIRE 288 256 208 256
WIRE 816 256 816 240
FLAG 288 320 0
FLAG 112 336 0
FLAG 112 176 0
FLAG 160 96 g
FLAG 208 256 cap
FLAG 384 160 0
FLAG 736 320 0
FLAG 816 304 0
FLAG 864 320 0
FLAG 960 304 0
FLAG 656 240 cap
FLAG 480 160 0
FLAG 464 496 0
FLAG 464 432 cap
FLAG 608 576 2
FLAG 608 656 0
FLAG 608 416 1
FLAG 608 496 0
FLAG 464 656 0
FLAG 464 592 cap
FLAG -128 800 0
FLAG -128 736 cap
SYMBOL voltage 112 240 R0
WINDOW 0 39 73 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value pwl 0 0 1 1
SYMBOL cap 272 256 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value Q=A*epsilon*log(d+V(g))
SYMBOL voltage 112 80 R0
WINDOW 0 39 73 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value sin 0 10u 1k
SYMBOL bv 384 64 R0
WINDOW 3 -13 128 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value i=-A*epsilon/(d+V(g))
SYMBOL e 864 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName E1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL cap 944 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value {A*epsilon}
SYMBOL bi2 736 320 M180
WINDOW 0 27 -3 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -20 -27 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName B2
SYMATTR Value I=i(c2)/(d+v(g))
SYMBOL res 464 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName Rtest
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL cap 448 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value Q=v(1)
SYMBOL bi2 608 576 R0
SYMATTR InstName B3
SYMATTR Value I=A*epsilon/(d+v(g)) Rpar=1g Cpar=1 ic=0
SYMBOL bi2 608 416 R0
SYMATTR InstName B4
SYMATTR Value I=idt(A*epsilon/(d+v(g))) Rpar=1
SYMBOL cap 448 592 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value Q=v(2)
SYMBOL cap -144 736 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value Q=5.752862898435809f*atan(0.1020620726159658*((10*sin(6283.185307179586*time))/(cos(6283.185307179586*time)+1)+2))
TEXT -48 432 Left 2 !.tran 2m
TEXT -48 512 Left 2 !.parma A=0.1m epsilon=8.854p d=50u
TEXT -48 472 Left 2 !.opt plotwinsize=0
TEXT -48 560 Left 2 !.meas i1 find i(c1) at 0.4m\n.meas i2 find i(c1) at 1.2m\n.meas t1 find i(b2) at 0.4m\n.meas t2 find i(b2) at 1.2m\n.meas xx param epsilon
RECTANGLE Normal 1104 368 608 208
RECTANGLE Normal 1040 528 384 384
RECTANGLE Normal 1104 688 384 544
RECTANGLE Normal 560 368 64 208
```

Comment: I'm gonna need some time to digest all of this, but I really appreciate the help. Based on quick glances, the "cap" labels in the circuitry...can I assign those to capacitors elsewhere in the circuit? I'm wondering if I need to include one of these solutions in my original schematic entirely to get it working...and if doing so, would that impact the other parameters there in some way?

Comment: The labels are there for convenience, as the default node names that LTspice assigns, `Nxxx`, are not fixed and can be changed at the slightest modification of the connections. Here, it was much easier to connect all the caps by simply copy-pasting (F5) the label. Since the test involves a voltage source, its internal resistance is zero, unless specified, and the current is what's needed. Therefore, all the caps (and `B2`) can be safely connected in parallel. The parameters can be defined in any way, here they're bogus choices. Choose whichever method suits your needs.

Comment: I had to go then, but there is one more thing: I have not used `x` in my answer because, as I understood your question, you need to vary the capacitance according to an *external* source. But if the capacitor is varying according to the voltage applied to it, then `x` can be used, and even safely, in `A*e*log(d+x)`, because the law of variation is `x`, itself. In my answer, the variation is given by `time`, not `sin()`, because you can have `sin(1)` which is non-variable (i.e. static, `sin()` only varies due to the `time` factor), which makes `time` the variable of integration.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and explaining things in detail. Your comments on 'x' make sense. However, I'm still a little confused on how to actually use that current variable in my overall circuit; specifically, if I were to go about this with the voltage-dependent voltage source with I(B2). I think it's important to note that these capacitors are not the main outputs of the circuit but rather, an early portion of the circuitry. So, I'm wondering if using a current source (with the correct capacitance value) will be seen by the circuit as an actual capacitor. This disconnect is my confusion.

Comment: In practise, the capacitor will have some sort of load, even the very high input of an opamp. Plus, the formula is a function of the (derivative of the) voltage across it, so if you're worrying that `I(B2)` might cause GV levels, it won't (unless numeric noise is a factor, or you're deliberately applying such voltages). Besides, internally, an inductor is represented as a voltage source, and a capacitor as a current source. I'd say to just try it, since this is a simulator, and you won't see any magic smoke. But if things don't go as expected, there's always ee.se. :-)

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your time and post here what I ended up doing in case somebody needs help. I have an idea of what my capacitance change is, so I made a voltage source with the nominal capacitance as the DC offset and the frequency-dependent stuff to be the expected capacitance fluctuation. I then used that voltage source as a variable in my Q formula, i.e.,  Q = V(capacitance)*x, (Q = C*V) since x is the voltage across the capacitor. This ended up working very nicely and didn't require any complicated functions. Again, thanks for the help and hopefully this thread will help  others!