# Variable capacitor in LTSPICE

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis, analog, ltspice

I am trying to simulate variable capacitor in LTSpice. I have gone trough solution for variable capacitor with respect to voltage. But I want to change it with respect to relative permittivity. Any answers would be appreciated?

Comment: What physical system are you trying to model? Do you want to know what happens, for example, if you physically move a dielectric sheet in and out from between the capacitor plates? Or do you just want to know how the capacitance of a simple parallel plate capacitor varies if you change the dielectric material used?

Comment: Also, please share a link to the "solution for variable capacitor with respect to voltage" so we know where you're starting from..

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/513177/95619)? Or ask in the [LTspice group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/).

Comment: Actually, I designed Planar capacitive sensor for the purpose of ice detection. as Ice forms on the sensor, the relative permittivity changes, right? So I want to simulate this environment with variable capacitor in LTSpice.

Comment: Just use a .step command and simulate with a range of capacitances.  If nothing else changes, the capacitance will vary directly with permittivity.

Comment: Thanks. can you elaborate how to write .step command?