# Vary Capacitance in LTSpice

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, simulation, microphone, variable

I would like to model a condenser microphone in LTSpice. This kind of microphone has a variable capacitance dependent on the incoming pressure. I know how to vary a resistor with time, but unfortunately these methods don't work for capacitors. I know this has been asked a couple years ago, but this soultion ist not satisfactory for me. So I'm hoping there is some better method available today.

[image: Varying the resistance works fine]

The capacitor has a constant capacitance and a smaller linear variabled capacitance (modelled by a sine function or whatever). When I try the methods from above for a capacitor, It get the folowing error:

[image]

Thank you already in advance!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/380581/95619)? Or [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/513177/95619)? I honestly doubt these questions (at least) didn't show up when you wrote your question.

Answer (score 3):

I remember publishing in 2004 a column in the PCIM magazine (US) where I described how to emulate variable resistors, capacitors and inductors. The capacitor was done in a very simple way and could also work in ac if I remember well. Below is the simple architecture I used and you can probably duplicate it in LTspice:

[image]

And if you compare the waveforms obtained with a SPICE capacitor and the varicap component I created, it delivered identical waveforms:

[image]