# LTSpice: Use component's terminal voltages in behavioral model expression

Tags: ltspice, simulation

Is there a way to use a component's terminal voltages in a behavioral model expression without referencing node names? For example, the following circuit implements a voltage-dependent nonlinear capacitance.
[image]

The circuit works as I intended it to, and I would like to be able to use this behavioral current source many times in a circuit simulation without having to label node names and edit the expression in the behavioral model. I've (unsuccessfully) tried the following:

I=table(V(x),0,10u,10,1u)*ddt(V(x))

I=table(V(+,-),0,10u,10,1u)*ddt(V(+,-))

Is there a way to generically refer to the terminal voltages of a device in its behavioral expression?

Comment: Make a subcircuit and a 2-terminal schematic symbol that calls the subcircuit.

Comment: Never had to do this before. Assuming you've tried all the usual things most of us would try, then I'm going to reach for something creative. Try creating a vsource inside your subcircuit with DC 0.0 and connect one end of it to the node of interest coming into the .SUBCKT. Tie the other end to a labeled node that goes nowhere. Then take V(nowherenode) and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah. That worked fine. Just try it out. Works real nice.

Comment: Call me dense, but if this resides inside a subcircuit, then the only time when you need to apply a label to a node is inside that subcircuit definition. The symbol may be placed on un-named nodes, while the internal reference will stay forever as long as the subcircuit definition exists. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Do you understand what the OP meant in saying this circuit is useful for something? All I see is a simple PWL that drives a voltage difference between two nodes and a B source that drives a current through V2 (which is effectively a dead short for all intents and purposes.) I'm not sure what the B source is doing for the OP. So I'd like a clue, if you have one. (The OP appears to be non-responsive or I'd just ask the OP. I'm hoping maybe you have some clues.)

Comment: @jonk Unfortunately, I have none. The way I read it then was that it's a simplification and, thus, what we see is just the "concept". Reading it again, now, it doesn't seem like that, anymore, so this part: "*The circuit works as I intended it to*" suddenly seems strange. Otherwise, if OP wants a behavioural capacitance, there are [alternatives](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/380612/95619).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks. I'm clueless. The OP is non-responsive. So I guess that's where it ends. Thanks, again. :)

Comment: Hi, OP here. Sorry I was away for a few days. The behavioral current source models a voltage-dependent nonlinear capacitance. For example, the output capacitance of a high voltage FET which can vary by two orders of magnitude over its intended operating range. The behavioral current source implements i=C*dv/dt where C comes from a lookup table. The PWL source is simply to test the model to see that it's working correctly. I want to use this non-linear capacitance multiple times in my circuit, e.g. 4 times for an H-Bridge.

Comment: The suggestion to use a subcircuit sounds like it would work. I'll give that a try. I was hoping there would be a straightforward way in LTSpice for the behavioral current source to reference its terminal voltages without referencing node names. PSpice, for example, has that capability. If a subcircuit is required, that's not terrible. Just a bit more work.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I read the post that you linked to about creating a behavioral capacitance where the capacitance varies with time, but I'm not sure how to apply it to a voltage dependent capacitance.

Comment: @RTPeasant A problem may have been how little you provided in the question and how much we were forced to guess about the goals, etc. Had there been more written at the time, including what I'm seeing now and hopefully still more through visual aides, I think useful answers might have arrived.

Comment: @RTPeasant FET capacitance is one of the truly profound failings of Spice. Meyer caps are both incomplete and inconsistent, such that it is impossible to develop charge functions, when differentiated, yield Meyer caps. End of story. So I get the desire. It just seems to me more could have been written. I was confused. That much I can say.

Comment: @RTPeasant Here's a question I still have: Do you want to have to adapt the equation in every case to global circuit node names? Or, as I do, don't you imagine it might be easier to write a generic SUBCKT with default parameters that can be over-ridden as needed?

Comment: @RTPeasant You cauld also try to follow some links in there. For example [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/513185/95619) tells about what `x` is and what it does in a behavioural capacitor. I still think your problem is the voltage source directly across the capacitor, but only unless you need the current.

Comment: @jonk I'd like to not have to adapt the equation at all, once I have the model tweaked to my satisfaction. I'd like to be able to cut-and-paste the behavioral current source anywhere in the circuit with no regards to the net names that it is connecting to. I think that is the intent of the SUBCKT approach.

Comment: @RTPeasant Exactly! So I'm baffled when you write, *"The suggestion to use a subcircuit sounds like it would work. I'll give that a try. I was hoping there would be a straightforward way ..."* This implies (perhaps incorrectly) that you are trying to ***avoid*** SUBCKT because it's somehow *not straightforward* enough for you. Now, you seem to ***embrace*** it. I'm confused. Which is it?

Comment: @jonk I was hoping to avoid the SUBCKT because it's another level of complexity that I have to go learn and manage. For example, when I share the circuit with a colleague, I assume I have to share the symbol and subcircuit model that I create, which is more details to manage. I'm embracing it now because it appears that it may be the only way to avoid having to adapt the model equation for every instance in my circuit. So it appears to be the lesser of two evils, if you will.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for the links that you provided. I think my question is the same as this one: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380581/ltspice-capacitance-dependend-on-voltage-source
I'm trying to create a voltage-dependent capacitance. The answer to that question described how to make a time-dependent capacitance, but not a voltage-dependent capacitance. I don't see how to make a voltage-dependent capacitance with a charge equation.

Comment: cont... 
I found this article that describes a method for making a voltage-dependent capacitance with a behavioral current source:
https://www.ema-eda.com/sites/ema/files/resources/files/nonlinear-capacitor-model.pdf
I was hoping to implement this in LTSpice using a behavioral current source and a variable like the special variable x for capacitors to indicate the voltage across the BI element. It appears that doesn't exist for the BI element.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen you wrote "I still think your problem is the voltage source directly across the capacitor, but only unless you need the current." Please note the voltage source in my circuit image is for test purposes only. It's just the behavioral current source (i.e. the voltage-dependent capacitance) that I'm interested in.

Comment: @RTPeasant You don't have to share the symbol. I usually just grab "any" other symbol I like (resistor, capacitor, whatever) and turn it into an X-type card and link it to the SUBCKT. The SUBCKT itself can just be on the schematic, itself. [Here's an example that shows all kinds of them and a repurposed vacuum tube symbol that I liked.]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebwd5.png) That's just me having tons of fun with it. You don't make to make things that messy, of course. That's an extreme example intended to be an extreme example. Put everything into the one schematic. No problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that tip. I learned something new today. I got the symbol and subcircuit working. I'd post a picture of my solution if I knew how to do that. The subcircuit is simply a behavioral current source with I=table(V(I+,I-),0, 4000p,10,1000p, 20, 500p, 40, 300p, 80, 200p, 300, 100p, 400, 90p)*ddt(V(I+,I-)), which implements i=C(v)*dv/dt for my voltage-dependent capacitance. I+ and I- are the terminals of the behavioral current source. I don't need to edit any expressions or be concerned with node names in my top level circuit.

Comment: Looks like I don't have enough reputation points to post pictures in a comment? But I can post a picture in an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion by @qrk worked. "Make a subcircuit and a 2-terminal schematic symbol that calls the subcircuit."

Here is my symbol on the left and subcircuit on the right. This is also an answer to the question of how to produce a voltage-dependent nonlinear capacitance, which was really my goal all along.
[image]

Comment: Glad that it works. One minor warning, though: working with explicit derivatives, such as `ddt()`, may cause large to very large noise due to the finite timestep and precision. Also, I see now you've used the labels `I+` and `I-`, which are used inside the behavioural expression -- aren't these what you wanted to avoid?

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to name nets and modify the I=f() expression for every instance to match those net names. With the subcircuit on the left, I can just copy and paste it where I need it with no regards to net naming.